# Connecting mobile device via GPRS

Tags: mobile, gps, gprs, tracker

As i understand, mobile devices (gps trackers, etc) are able to send data using two ways:

- SMS, that is being received with special device, connected to the server
- GPRS (straight connect to the server)

But what about sending data from the server to the device? I want to connect to my gps tracker and ask it to send me it's location and other similar data.

First time i thought that i can do this with sms - sure, but it is quite expensive... and after playing around with service http://orange.gps-trace.com/ i found that they do not use sms (you have to pay for this).

So, how to they send data from server to my device without using sms?

Answer (score 0):

Use notifications. And the advantage of notification is that if your app is closed, once notification is opened, app would start.